# I have problem with Sound Pitch in JavaScript, every time the code is run, the pitch is higher instead of the normal value and I don't know what to do

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am writing code to manipulate sound because I want to make a "simulator of standing on the street" (only sound for now), but every time the code is run, the pitch of the sound is higher than the normal value, ChatGPT 3.5 helped in writing the code, I am currently developing the idea but this situation is quite a big obstacle, I need the code to apply the Doppler effect to the noise to make it sound like a car passing by, for now I am at the stage of testing various settings and variables, I would be grateful for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Audio Control</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="playButton">Play</button>
    <button id="stopButton">Stop</button>
    <input type="range" id="volumeSlider" min="0.1" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5">
    <input type="range" id="pitchSlider" min="0.10" max="2" step="0.01" value="1">
    <button id="animateButton">Animate Pitch</button>
    <div id="pitchDisplay">Pitch: 1</div>
    <div id="volumeDisplay">Volume: 0.5</div>
    <div id="animationStatus">Animation Status: Stopped</div>

    <script src="audio_control.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const audio = new Audio('sample.mp3');

    const playButton = document.getElementById('playButton');
    const stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton');
    const volumeSlider = document.getElementById('volumeSlider');
    const pitchSlider = document.getElementById('pitchSlider');
    const animateButton = document.getElementById('animateButton');
    const pitchDisplay = document.getElementById('pitchDisplay');
    const volumeDisplay = document.getElementById('volumeDisplay');
    const animationStatus = document.getElementById('animationStatus');

    let volume = parseFloat(volumeSlider.value);
    let pitch = parseFloat(pitchSlider.value);

    if (pitch < 0.10) {
        pitch = 0.10;
        pitchSlider.value = 0.10;
    } else if (pitch > 2) {
        pitch = 2;
        pitchSlider.value = 2;
    }

    audio.volume = volume;
    audio.playbackRate = Math.pow(2, pitch);

    playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        audio.play();
    });

    stopButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
    });

    volumeSlider.addEventListener('input', function() {
        volume = parseFloat(this.value);
        audio.volume = volume;
        volumeDisplay.textContent = `Volume: ${volume.toFixed(2)}`;
    });

    pitchSlider.addEventListener('input', function() {
        pitch = parseFloat(this.value);
        audio.playbackRate = Math.pow(2, pitch);
        pitchDisplay.textContent = `Pitch: ${pitch.toFixed(2)}`;
    });

    animateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        animatePitch();
    });

    function animatePitch() {
        animationStatus.textContent = 'Animation Status: Running';
        let duration = 5000;
        let startPitch = 0.10;
        let endPitch = 2;

        let startTime = null;

        function animate(currentTime) {
            if (!startTime) startTime = currentTime;
            let progress = (currentTime - startTime) / duration;
            if (progress > 1) progress = 1;

            pitch = startPitch + (endPitch - startPitch) * progress;
            audio.playbackRate = Math.pow(2, pitch);
            pitchDisplay.textContent = `Pitch: ${pitch.toFixed(2)}`;

            if (progress < 1) {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            } else {
                animationStatus.textContent = 'Animation Status: Stopped';
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        const volumeDelta = (volume - audio.volume) / 10;
        const pitchDelta = (Math.pow(2, pitch) - audio.playbackRate) / 10;

        if (Math.abs(volumeDelta) > 0.001) {
            audio.volume += volumeDelta;
        }

        if (Math.abs(pitchDelta) > 0.001) {
            audio.playbackRate += pitchDelta;
        }

        volumeDisplay.textContent = `Volume: ${audio.volume.toFixed(2)}`;
    }, 100);
});
```

I tried changing the maximum and minimum values, asked ChatGPT and it did not find a solution.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but i think maybe the slider step should be 0.1/12 or 0.008333, since you would want the speed or frequency to double every 12 steps